# Hot Reload applying changes but not refreshing page in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, hot-reload, visual-studio-2022

I've just migrated a .NET 5 app to .NET 6 and am trying to get hot reloading working.

When I run my app, change a value and hit the hot reload button (or use the hot reload on save option), Visual Studio informs me that "Code changes were applied successfully":

[image]

Despite this, the changes are not reflected on my app. I've run the app using Full IIS, IIS Express and using the dotnet cli, though there is no difference between them. The page simply does not reload.

Answer (score 1):

I battled with this until coming across [an article by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/net-6-hot-reload-and-refused-to-connect-to-ws-because-it-violates-the-content-security-policy-directive-because-web-sockets) that describes how using a restrictive Content Security Policy (CSP) may cause problems with hot reload.

The way hot reload works in .NET 6 is that it injects a script before the closing `</body>` tag (side note: if you don't have a body tag, hot reload also won't work). This script sets up a websocket connection to your server that listens for changes made as part of the hot reload process. If you have specified a whitelist of ConnectSources in your CSP that doesn't include a websockets address pointing to your development server, you'll get something like the following error in the console:

[image]

Adding the expected ConnectSources to your CSP will resolve the error in the console, and hot reload should start working again. Note, I'm using the popular NWebsec package to set up my CSPs.

```
    var customConnectSources = new List<string>
    {
        "https://*.signalr.net" // example
    };

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // make exceptions to allow hot reload to work
        customConnectSources.Add("ws://localhost:*");
        customConnectSources.Add("wss://localhost:*");
    }

    app.UseCsp(options => options
        .DefaultSources(s => s
            .Self())
        .ConnectSources(s => s
            .Self()
            .CustomSources(customConnectSources.ToArray())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with making Hot Reload to work for the same reason as in the ajbeaven's answer (ws is not allowed for 'self'). Adding this into  section in index.cshtml or _Layout.cshtml will help. Additionally, if by chance you work on IdentityServer project, then CSP is set in SecurityHeaderAttributes.cs and values in cshtml files are ignored.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src ws://localhost:*;">
```